# RallyAPI: How do I create a UserStory and relate it to a Feature?

Tags: c#, api, rally

So, I'm writing an app to 'flesh out' new clients in Rally. It will have tools to create templates which will add first:

1. add a 'Feature'
2. add 'UserStories' under that 'Feature'
3. add 'Tasks' under those 'UserStories' individually

I have figured out step 1. But how to associate anything I can't figure out from the horrible and cryptic documentation. Here's what I have so far:

```
 var FeatureToAdd = _featureRepository.GetFeatures().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 2);          

        // Initialize the REST API. You can specify a web service version if needed in the constructor.
        RallyRestApi restApi = GetRallyRestApi();

        //Create an item
        DynamicJsonObject toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();
        toCreate["Name"] = FeatureToAdd.Name;
        toCreate["Description"] = FeatureToAdd.Description;

        // important to which this belongs, but I no ID I ever use works
        //toCreate["Workspace"] = "/workspace/" + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RallyAPIWorkspaceID"];
        //toCreate["Project"] = "/project/XXXXX";
        //toCreate["Iteration"] = "/iteration/XXXXXX";

        // create feature - feature is under PortfolioItem
        CreateResult createFeatureResult = restApi.Create("PortfolioItem/Feature", toCreate);

        // scrape ID off the end of the reference
        var pureId = createFeatureResult.Reference.Substring(createFeatureResult.Reference.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        // add UserStories
        foreach (UserStory u in FeatureToAdd.UserStories)
        {
            toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();
            toCreate["Name"] =u.Name;
            toCreate["Description"] = u.Description;
            toCreate["WorkProduct"] = "PortfolioItem/Feature/" + pureId;
            //toCreate["WorkProduct"] = createFeatureResult.Reference;<- tried this too

            // hierarchicalrequirement = UserStory
            CreateResult createUserStoryResult = restApi.Create("hierarchicalrequirement", toCreate);
        }
```

Running this creates both, but no association happens. I get a warning:

```
Ignored JSON element hierarchicalrequirement.WorkProduct during processing of this request.
```

Why did it arbitrarily ignore this?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ignored WorkProduct because WorkProduct is not a valid field on HierarchicalRequirement.  The field you want to specify to set the feature parent of a story is called PortfolioItem.

```
toCreate["PortfolioItem"] = Ref.GetRelativeRef(createFeatureResult.Reference);
```

Also, object relationships are specified as in WSAPI as refs (/type/id) so you can just directly pass in the reference from the createFeatureResult.

Sorry you're finding the api to be frustrating.  It definitely has some weird dark corners but once you use it a bit and get a feel for how the various domain objects are related I think you'll find it to be quite powerful and consistent.

Comment: Now, I just need a list of all the proper terms and relationships. So, now, how do I add 'tasks' under these 'userStories'? what's the term I should use?

Comment: figured it out:   toCreate["WorkProduct"] = Ref.GetRelativeRef(createUserStoryResult.Reference);