# RallyAPI: How to create UserStory and relate it to an EpicStory

Tags: c#, rally

I previously asked how to create a '`UserStory`' and relate it to a '`Feature`' in RallyApi [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830539/rallyapi-how-do-i-create-a-userstory-and-relate-it-to-a-feature)

Now, I'm asking how to create an `EpicStory`. Then, create a `UserStory` and related it to the `EpicStory`.

Below, I marked it where I'm getting an error. I don't know what parameter to set. The error is: ***"Could not set value for Portfolio Item: Cannot use type UserStory in attribute Portfolio Item"***

Here's what I have so far:

```
 // Initialize the REST API. You can specify a web service version if needed in the constructor.
        RallyRestApi restApi = GetRallyRestApi();

        // Create their Json object for this Feature
        DynamicJsonObject toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();
        toCreate["Name"] = FeatureToAdd.Name;
        toCreate["Description"] = FeatureToAdd.Description;

        // create feature - (feature is under PortfolioItem)
        CreateResult createFeatureResult = restApi.Create("PortfolioItem/Feature", toCreate);

        // add Epic Stories
        foreach (EpicStory e in FeatureToAdd.EpicStories)
        {
            toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();
            toCreate["Name"] = e.Name;
            toCreate["Description"] = e.Description;
            toCreate["PortfolioItem"] = Ref.GetRelativeRef(createFeatureResult.Reference);
            // hierarchicalrequirement = UserStory
            CreateResult createEpicStoryResult = restApi.Create("hierarchicalrequirement", toCreate);

            // foreach userstory create the USerStory and each subsequent Task
            foreach (UserStory u in e.UserStories)
            {
                toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();
                toCreate["Name"] = u.Name;
                toCreate["Description"] = u.Description;
                toCreate["PortfolioItem"] = Ref.GetRelativeRef(createEpicStoryResult.Reference); //<-This is the problem; says "Could not set value for Portfolio Item: Cannot use type UserStory in attribute Portfolio Item" 
                // hierarchicalrequirement = UserStory
                CreateResult createUserStoryResult = restApi.Create("hierarchicalrequirement", toCreate);

                // -- add tasks for each UserStory
                foreach (eBayData.Models.Task t in u.Tasks)
                {
                    toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();
                    toCreate["Name"] = t.Name;
                    toCreate["Description"] = t.Description;
                    toCreate["WorkProduct"] = Ref.GetRelativeRef(createUserStoryResult.Reference);
                    // task
                    CreateResult createUserStoryTaskResult = restApi.Create("task", toCreate);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm a C# dev that spends a lot of time in Rally.  From looking at the API and the Rally UI, I think you need to change the problem line from `toCreate["PortfolioItem"]` to `toCreate["Parent"]`.  If that works for you, please comment back and I'll put this in as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Bingo! I saw that and was going to try it after lunch, but you beat me to it ;) Thanks. I'll mark it as the answer if you post it.

Comment: Glad that worked for you ('cas I've never actually worked with the Rally API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the API and the Rally UI, I think you need to change the problem line from `toCreate["PortfolioItem"]` to `toCreate["Parent"]`.